# How do I get the max of {300, 200, 400} and the max of {3.5, 5.5, 10.5} to print in Java?

Tags: java, max

```
public class Max_Arr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int largeArray[] = {300, 200, 400};
        int largest = largeArray[0];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (largeArray[i] > largest) {
                largest = largeArray[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The largest value in the array is " + largest);
        double largeArray2[] = {3.5, 5.5, 10.5};
        double largest2 = largeArray2[0];
        for (double i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (largeArray2[i] > largest2) {
                largest2 = largeArray[0];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The largest value in the array is " + largest2);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print the max value from both arrays but am getting incompatible type errors. Can you guys please help?

Comment: please please please try to search a little before coming here. Google your error. Your trace will tell you exactly what line is causing the issue.

Comment: `for (double i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {` is your problem.  `double` can't be used as a index into an array, use `for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {` instead, although, I think `for (int i = 1; i < largeArray2.length; i++) {` would be more accurate

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, sorry, wrong footed due to the for loop starting at zero as well.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Took me a few seconds to figure it all out too ;)

Comment: sleepToken I tried that and it didn't really help me. I was in a rush and needed to get all my programming language homework done. And this problem was the last one. So I was getting stressed and needed to ask about it here.

Comment: SO is the wrong site for such situations. It is not a tutoring website but Q&A. StackOverflow is about high quality questions and high quality answers. If you do not invest 10 minutes into your question phrasing, formatting, prior research and a [mcve] with full error information, you will receive lots of down-votes. Please familiarize yourself with [ask] and [help], thanks.

Comment: Zahuza My bad. I don’t always use Stack Exchange. Most of the time I just Google the errors

Comment: I mean Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is ...

```
for (double i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
```

It's a little unobvious at first, but `double` can't be used as a index into an array

Instead, you should use

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
```

Although, I think

```
for (int i = 1; i < largeArray2.length; i++) {
```

would be more accurate

Comment: @prsvr It is, but that's not what you are doing.  You're using the value as a index into an array, arrays can only be indexed via an `int`, this is why you're getting a incompatibility error

Comment: I was confused about that because before I was getting the "incompatible type" error I was getting the "possible lossy conversion from double to int" So I tried changing everything to double, then to float, etc. At that point,. I was getting stressed because I had to get this homework done by tonight, and was losing my ability to think straight lol.

Comment: you can use with foreach-loop with your double datatype. for (double v : largeArray)

Comment: @Samakaab That would also work, but the OP has excluded the need to inspect the first item ... this or that